# Составить все варианты сочетаний элементов массива

Tags: html, javascript

Есть js массив, в котором есть простые элементы, например, обычные буквы, и есть элементы, которые сами являются массивами. Надо составить все сочитания элементов.

Пример:

> `1
> авп
> к
> 4
> 5п`

Надо получить:

> `1ак45, 1вк45, 1пк45, 1ак4п, ...`

В общем, надо все такие сочетания составить. Длина общего массива и встроенных массивов переменная, положение и количество встроенных массивов тоже меняется.
Подкиньте идей как организовать алгоритм перебора?

Comment: Поседнее сочетание в Вашем примере это "1пк4п" ?

Comment: Да. Вроде бы должен быть простой и стандартный алгоритм, но самостоятельно я "велосипед" пока сделать не могу. И где прочитать по-быстрому тоже не знаю. Поэтому решил здесь вопрос задать.

Comment: Если не секрет - зачем вам это?

Comment: Разрабатываю сервис ["Online размножение и рерайт текста"](http://www.gsgen.ru/index.php?id=5). Случайные соединения элементов работают, а вот выбрать попорядку все пока не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, на скорую руку, так:

```js
var i, j, k, arr, tmp1, tmp2, c, c1;

arr = ['1', 'авп', 'к', '4', '5п'];

tmp1 = [''];
tmp2 = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  c = arr[i];
  for (j = 0; j < tmp1.length; j++) {
    c1 = tmp1[j];
    for (k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
      tmp2.push(c1 + c[k]);
    }
  }

  tmp1 = tmp2;
  tmp2 = [];
}

console.log(tmp1);
```

P.S: В текущем виде, элементы `arr` - либо строка, либо массив

Comment: Большое спасибо, Ваш код удалось "завести" с полоборота. На первый взгляд работает как надо. На свежую голову посмотрю, что можно будет улучшить применительно к условиям моей задачи.
Как только Вы так точно смогли понять, что мне нужно? Удивительно.
Ещё раз большое спасибо.